# Return bad value json

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a script that sends the values ​​to the controller. Everything works fine when the value of the digit. At values ​​larger displays only the last digit. String assigned to rigidly as bad. Debugger displayed on the controller is that the value passed is correct.

script

```
...
$.each(data, function (i, kkk) {
    document.getElementById("sum").value = kkk
});
```

controller

```
public ActionResult Fun(int some, int some1)
{
string xxx = "18";
    if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return Json(xxx
            , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

view

```
<input type="text" name="sum" id="sum"/>
```

displays 8...should be 18.
Why is this happening? Why the return value is truncated?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why the return value is truncated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the result is treated as a char array. When you iterate over `data`, it sets the last char as the value of the input. Get rid of the loop and it should be fine.

```
document.getElementById("sum").value = data;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [jQuery each function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

It is setting the last character in the string to the value.

What you want to do is just set the value equal to the data returned without the loop.

I would use this:

```
   $.ajax({
// edit to add steve's suggestion.
url: "/ControllerName/ActionName",
success: function(data) {
     document.getElementById("sum").value = data;
}
});
```